# Windows xp pro admin account locked out

Tags: windows-xp, passwords, administrator

For some reason my xp machine was using a user callcomp1, even though I had the main user set up as me. When I went into users it only showed one user.

So, to get rid of this is I ran Userpasswords2 deleted the Comp1 user then unchecked user must enter a name and password. It then promoted me for a password for the admin user.  I typed it in, noted it down. Reset the machine then got the login screen and  a password error.

I have tried everything from:

F8 SAFE mode- it does the same and asks for a password and won't let me in

Blank password - tried this

I've also tried Comp1 and my other user name, nothing worked.

Does anyone know how I can get back in my machine???

I don't have the xp disc and really don't want to lose my data. I have lots of pics of my kids on there that I can't bare to part with.

Comment: Have you tried using the "Reset Password" link under the password box?

Comment: If you can access a CD writer and the Internet then you could download the Ultimate Boot CD (UBCD) and use it's NTOffline Password & registry editing tool... it's a bootable LiveCD. You can use the utility to change or remove the account password in question.

Comment: @zain.Ali there is only the standard Windows login which has username and password

Comment: @Funky - So enable the default Administrator user then and log into that.

Comment: How do I do that? All I have is a login box. @ramhound